# ReactJS component - control visibility outside ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a re-usable UI module which exposes pure Typescript APIs for creating the window and managing visibility.  The fact that it internally uses ReactJS is hidden away in the implementation details.  When the host of module calls the 'createWindow' method, I essentially render my ReactJS component under the given parent element.  But I also want the host to be able to toggle the component visbility as well.  A simplified version of my code is below:

```
export class ApiImpl implements Api {
  public constructor() {
    this._windowMap = new Map<string, MyWindow>();
  }

  public createWindow(id: string, parentElement: HTMLElement): void {
    if (!this._windowMap.has(id)) {
      this._windowMap.set(id, new MyWindow(id, parentElement));
  }

  public toggleVisible(id: string, display?: boolean): void {
      const window: MyWindow | undefined = this._windowMap.get(id);
      if (window) {
        window.toggleVisible(display);
      }
  }

  private _windowMap: Map<string, MyWindow>;
}

export class MyWindow {
  public constructor(id: string, parentElement: HTMLElement): void {
    ReactDOM.render((
      <MyComponent id={ id } />
    ), parentElement);
  }

  public toggleVisible(display?: boolean): void {
    /* proper way to toggle visibility of component? */
  }
}
```

So basically I'm not sure how to control the component visibility from outside the ReactJS component.  I've tried passing a 'visible' flag into the component properties and if that flag is false, put a style of "display: 'none'" on the component, but updating the flag in MyWindow doesn't cause the component to "react".  Do I need to use 'React.useState' or some other hook to get the component to react to an external variable?

Comment: I'd probably store the visibility state within the react component and have it listen to a custom event and update the state in the callback

Comment: Thanks Ross.  That's what I ended up doing, as there were a few more 'events' the component needed to listen to from up above.